# Using a button to load a kv file

Tags: python, kivy

Hi all my question is a basic one. I'm using a `.kv` file in which I have defined a button that changes screens. I would like to use that button to load `.kv` file. I can use `builder.load(kv2.kv)` ?

I've tried a bunch of different ways writing it out. The `stats.kv` file loads all my RPG stats. If I remove the builder statement, I just get the next screen. All my widgets are in a different `.kv` files for ease of debugging purposes. I just need to load multiple `.kv` files within a `.kv` file.

However this error always occurs:

`AttributeError: 'RevengeApp' object has no attribute 'builder'`

Button in `.kv` file:

```
Button:
       text: "Confirm"
       on_press: app.builder.load(stats.kv)
       on_release: app.root.current = "AStats"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you assign the `Builder` object to the `builder` attribute of your app? because that's what your kv code seems to expect.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
```

[…]

```
class RevengeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.builder = Builder
```

should do it.

But you could also just import Builder directly in your kv code by doing

```
#:import builder kivy.lang.Builder
```

at the top of your kv file, and then replace your `app.builder.load` with `builder.load_file` in your `on_press` binding.

Comment: Thank you I imported builder in my py file but forgot to in my kv file all is working now.